# Htaccess redirect only one URL with query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect only this URL https://www.mywebsite.com/?lang=en to https://www.mywebsite.com/en/

I try with this without success

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} https://www.mywebsite.com/  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=en
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/en/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put an empty question mark `?` at the end of your rule's destination to discard old query string from the new url .

To redirect `/?lang=en` to `/en/` you can use the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=en
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.mywebsite.com/en/? [R=301,L]
```

Otherwise your new url would look something like `/en/?lang=en` .

Clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks this work, and is there a generic way perhaps to auto redirect https://www.mywebsite.com/something/?lang=en to https://www.mywebsite.com/en/something ?

Comment: @Laurent 

you can use :


`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=en
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.mywebsite.com/en%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]`

Comment: Yes it work and sorry if i have in old url 
the .html https://www.mywebsite.com/something.html?lang=en to remove it to have only https://www.mywebsite.com/en/something